# Why null assignment does not work?

Tags: javascript

In this code,

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">

        <script>
            window.onload = myfunc;
            function myfunc(){
                window['document'] = null;
                console.log(window['document']);    
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>My First Web Page</h1>
        <p>My first paragraph.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Despite null assignment, Why DOM interface `window['document']` is not null? as shown below...

[image]

Comment: Do you want instead clear the body of the page?

Comment: @JoseRocha yes, I want to clear the body of the page.

Comment: `window.onload=function(){
             document.body.innerHTML = "";
                  console.log(window['document']);
          }`

Comment: @JoseRocha Can we clear the head of the page?

Comment: Yes you can, but i dont see the advantage on that, just use `document.head.innerHTML = "" ;` if you are using jquery check empty() to. Best.Btw if you want to not show the page to someone in specific you should redirect them to a "not available" page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Window.document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/document) is a read only property of [`window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window).

---

> **Window.document** Read only
>
> Returns a reference to the document that the window contains.